# Real time chat app - logic

Tags: php, mysql, swift, socket.io

I'm developing a SWIFT mobile social application.

The app requests the web to call PHP files to fetch / modify data in the MySQL Database. Everything is fine, expect the chat.

---

There's a problem:

The chat uses socket.io to deliver / recieve real time messages. But also I do have to manage who can message who: whenever sending a message, it also calls the **sendMessage.php** file

**sendMessage.php** is basically checking if user1 can send the message to user2 and if so then encrypts and saves the message in the database.

The application checks if the sendMessage.php returns "success" and then sends the message to **user2**: but that is easily hackable. Anyone could modify the app and send out messages to everyone (even though the messages won't be saved to the database)

---

What is a good logic for real time messages?

Comment: "What is a good logic for real time messages?" You need to use node.js and combine it with socket.io to make real time messages possible.

Comment: I do and real time messaging works. Just the fact that I need to verify if user can send the messages to the other user.. it is hard